# How can I resolve this permissions error when adding members to a custom audience?

Tags: facebook-ads-api

We use the ads api to create and update custom audiences for our clients.

We've had two new users recently see errors that look like the following:

(#200) User XXXXXX can not update audience XXXXXXXX

They have both accepted Facebook custom audience terms of service and given ads management permissions to our app. Both are administrators on the related ad accounts.

Any ideas?

Comment: both users have definitely given the ads_management permission right?

Comment: Yes. The ads_management permission appears on the token permissions when I double check at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ In addition, we were able to create the custom audience using the token, but not actually add users to it, which seems odd.

Comment: sounds like a bug to me! you should create a bug here at http://developers.facebook.com/bugs - the access token will be needed to debug

Comment: Facing the same issue. Did you create the bug?

Comment: Did anyone figure this out? Running into the same exact issue.